# Magento custom registration success message after redirect to dashboard

Tags: php, magento, events, message

I need to extend the custom success message after the customer registration. Now after registration the user is redirected to the dashboard and the standard success message is shown: "Thank you for registering with...".

I need that this message changes base on the customer group attribute. I read on-line but didn't find a working solution... but I think I'm making it in the wrong way. I started from here: http://mydons.com/simple-example-using-magento-event-observer/ to make a custom observer on the customer_register_success event, so I made the module xml named Bbox_Regmess.xml in app/etc/modules:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Bbox_Regmess>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Bbox_Regmess>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Than I made the app/code/local/Bbox/Regmess/etc and app/code/local/Bbox/Regmess/Model folders with inside the config.xml:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Bbox_Regmess>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Bbox_Regmess>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <events>
      <customer_register_success>
        <observers>
          <Bbox_Regmess_Model_Observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Bbox_Regmess_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>Customregmess</method>
          </Bbox_Regmess_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
      </customer_register_success>
    </events>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

And the Observer.php that is just a first try to see if I'm able to add a custom success message:

```
<?php
    class Bbox_Regmess_Model_Observer {
        public function Customregmess($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();  //Fetches the current event
        $customer = $event->getCustomer();
            $eventmsg = "Current Event Triggered : <I>" . $event->getName() . "</I><br/> Currently Added Product : <I> " . $customer->getCustomerName()."</I>";
            //Adds Custom message to shopping cart
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($eventmsg);
        }
    }
?>
```

Now if a user registers to the shop, he get the standard registration message and there is not the custom $eventmsg

What I'm making wrong? There is another way to to that? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

looking deeper I found out the default success message is defined in the app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php at line 390 (just after the line 334 where there is the definition of customer_register_success event I'm trying to work with).
at line 390 there is the _welcomeCustomer function that is in charge of setting the success message, send confirmation email and set the success redirect url:

```
protected function _welcomeCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $isJustConfirmed = false)
{
    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
        $this->__('Thank you for registering with %s.', Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName())
    );

    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
        $isJustConfirmed ? 'confirmed' : 'registered',
        '',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
    );

    $successUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true));
    if ($this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl()) {
        $successUrl = $this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);
    }
    return $successUrl;
}
```

Is there any chance to extend this function so I can manage multiple success message base on the customer group?
I've look for some resource about it, but I didn't find anything usefull

Comment: You can overwrite this method with overwriting the AccountController.php

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must place the events tag in the global tag

`<config><global>...<events>...</events>...</global>...</config>`

EDIT:

and the observer file extends Varien_Event_Observer, at least that worked with mine

```
class Bbox_Regmess_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer{}
```

Comment: the global tag have to wrap also the modules one or only the events and/or the frontend? thanks

Comment: i have it like this: `<config>..<modules>..</modules>..<frontend>..</frontend>..<global><events>..</events>..</global>..</config>`

Comment: I've just made this changes but nothing change... still get the standard success message. I'don't know what is going wrong, it is a problem in the new massage creation or in the event observer itself? What do you think?

Comment: If you have seen my edit, to add the extends in the observer, try add a constructor: `public function __construct(){}` and try to just echo something in the Customregmess function, in this way you will see, if the observer works and is a problem with the code in the function or the observer is not triggered

Comment: Sorry, i noticed another thing, in the `<class>` tag i have the path to the observer, like `<class>regmess/observer</class>`